# php zlib compression support won't work

Tags: zlib, php

If I'm setting up in my php.ini the zlib compression support, won't really seems to work.

```
zlib.output_compression = On

; http://php.net/zlib.output-compression-level
zlib.output_compression_level = -1

; You cannot specify additional output handlers if zlib.output_compression
; is activated here. This setting does the same as output_handler but in
; a different order.
; http://php.net/zlib.output-handler
;zlib.output_handler =
```

I'm using php-5.3.9

I have been testing with the following php code, I must say I'm not a professional but seems like don't work.

```
<?php

$filename = tempnam('/tmp', 'zlibtest') . '.gz';
echo "<html>\n<head></head>\n<body>\n<pre>\n";
$s = "Only a test, test, test, test, test, test, test, test!\n";

// open file for writing with maximum compression
$zp = gzopen($filename, "w9");

// write string to file
gzwrite($zp, $s);

// close file
gzclose($zp);

// open file for reading
$zp = gzopen($filename, "r");

// read 3 char
echo gzread($zp, 3);

// output until end of the file and close it.
gzpassthru($zp);
gzclose($zp);

echo "\n";

// open file and print content (the 2nd time).
if (readgzfile($filename) != strlen($s)) {
        echo "Error with zlib functions!";
}
unlink($filename);
echo "</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n";

?>
```

there is no output

Comment: With which client did you test? What where the request headers and what the response?

Comment: Indeed, output will not be automatically compressed unless the client sends an `Accept-Encoding: gzip` or `Accept-Encoding: deflate` header

Comment: phpinfo() Accept-Encoding :gzip, deflate

Answer (score 0):

The zlib output handler has nothing to do with th `gz` file functions.

So there is something else wrong, turn on [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/error_reporting).

Otherwise the shown code is working fine. The "no output" behaviour is not reproducible.

Comment: I have been turning on error reporting and I got the following:Fatal error: Call to undefined function gzopen() in /var/www/kakuki/zlib.php on line 8
I have been trying to recompile php but without any results. In this case I was using --with-zlib. Was funny is that in phpecho() doesn't show me after compilation changes.